# Why doesn't Deckard know basic details about Replicants?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner

Obviously, the effect is to inform the audience but Deckard acts as if some of the information he's being given by Bryant is completely new to him, for example that they have a 4-year lifespan and that they're very hard to spot, not something you'd expect that an experienced Blade Runner would need to be told.

How could any Blade Runner not know these basic Replicant facts?

Comment: As far as I know, the 4-year lifespan was rather new. It was implemented with the latest Nexus-5 models and wasn't present on the other older models. Some kind of failsafe in case they go rogue.

Comment: Yeah the beginning of the conversation Deckard says something like “what’s this?” and  Bryant explains about the new(ish) Nexus 6 models. Deckard presumably knows about earlier models, but not Nexus 6. And doesn’t he tell Gaff that he quit at the beginning? He’s been out of the game a while, if I’m not mistaken. He’s only called back because Leon killed the best blade runner Bryant had.

Comment: They went rogue before, hence the need for Blade Runners but perhaps the 4-year lifespan had seemed to work until some went rogue even in the short period. But either Tyrell was lying to Batty or maybe the 4-year lifespan was a useful side effect of making higher performance Replicants.

Comment: @Clockwork - What's the source that the shortened lifespan was seen in the Nexus-5? Or was this a typo?

Comment: @Valorum Definitely a mistake on my end. I misremembered 6 as 5 for some reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was addressed in the [Marvel Comic adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Marvel_Comics_Super_Special:_Blade_Runner). In short, Rick Deckard has been out of the game for quite a few years. The last time he worked as a Blade Runner, he was taking out Nexus-***3*** Replicants.

Evidently those were easier to spot (albeit still disconcerting to Deckard, "*too smooth, too human*") and didn't have the same in-built lifespan limitations that Tyrell added to the Nexus-6 models to help cope with the fact that they're liable to go cuckoo if left to their own devices. Deckard is evidently being given new info, and presumably information that hasn't or won't be made available to the general public.

[image]

In the film's [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/122327.Blade_Runner), when we catch up with Deckard he's musing about what the *latest* Nexus androids would be like. It's clear that he's never encountered one.

> What were they like? Deckard wondered. The newest replicants. Or reps. Or robots. Or androids. Or skin jobs. Or whatever you wanted to call them as they came off the assembly lines, each new model more lifelike than the one before.
>
> How hard were they to control now? How hard were they to catch when
> they broke free? How hard were they to spot when they pre tended to be
> humans? How hard were they to kill?
>
> Deckard tried to stop wondering. He stared at his raw fish. He didn't
> want to imagine what it would be like to off the latest model Nexus.
> **The last runaway rep he had hunted down was a Nexus 3. Even that early
> model made him sick to his stomach when it went dead.** It was too close
> to seeing a real person die. And since then the Tyrell Corporation had
> kept its top brains working overtime to keep offering the most
> lifelike humanoid slaves on the market. Aimed at people willing to
> take the big leap offworld, the Tyrell Nexus line was the big reason
> why America stayed number one in the worldwide race to settle outer
> space.
>
> <sub><sup>[Blade Runner: A Story of the Future](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/122327.Blade_Runner)</sup></sub>

Comment: I think the interesting thing is that Tyrell was sort of the opponent of law enforcement. They could have easily made Replicants detectible in either obvious ways like skin tint or subtler ways, like something that could be scanned reliably using a simple electronic device but Tyrell did not do this.

Comment: @releseabe - But then they wouldn't have been 'more human than human'...

Comment: Right: this places Tyrell in opposition to law enforcement and it seems like in 2049, Wallace is an arch criminal, dangerous beyond any criminal in history it could be argued.

Comment: @releseabe - He would argue that he's a philanthropist

Comment: i am sure he would even as he guts newborn replicants and prepares to torture deckard. note also that wallace has been merely inconvenienced by k and deckard -- deckard and ana stelline remain in mortal danger, and now wallace knows everything. ana, whose illness limits her movements, will nonetheless have to flee.

Comment: @releseabe - For the greater good, you sometimes have to make sacrifices

Comment: do you think most humans want to occupy the stars? that is something wallace wants. most people want a place for themselves off-world but i doubt they care how many planets humans live on in total. wallace is a bad guy.

Comment: @releseabe - Wallace sees the big picture. With a biddable and breedable workforce, mankind could extend out so rapidly that even a cataclysm would struggle to halt our existence

Comment: Look, he is a piece of shit. I see what he does.

Comment: @releseabe Wallace is a piece of shit in all senses: 1- he is portrayed as a despicable human being, and 2- he is a shitty character in a movie that need not have been made at all :)

Comment: @AndresF.: 2049 had some great stuff, new ideas. The stuff with Joi was subtle and interesting.

Comment: @releaseabe Agreed, it had *some* nice ideas indeed (Joi was clever: it looks like a girlfriend, then K finds it was all a fabricated emotion -- or was it?), but most of the movie missed the mark. Wallace is stupid and Leto chews the scenery up. Luv is beyond stupid -- "I am the best!", really? Deckard showing up -- stupid. Rachael's clone getting killed -- dumb. The whole Rachael thing, actually. Essentially, this is a movie that didn't need to get made. BR ends perfectly, Deckard and Rachael escape and we are not privy to how their lives end, as should be. But Hollywood needs their sequels.